Modal Alert, stating buttons actions in alert message vs letting button speak for themselves
Forgive me if this is covered, new to ux and am curious if there are resources for the situation where we want more complex verbiage to describe an alert's (modal dialog alert where action from user is required) actions.
Im unsure if it is 'bad' to say in the alert message what the options are and have the buttons restate those options vs prompting that action is required and have the wording in the buttons speak for the action.  (note in this case action is required, cancel closes the alert but if they choose to proceed they will see the same alert)
For example imagine a modal
title: "no saved config"
message: "you are missing a config for {{list of entities with missing config}}"
buttons: [use default:primary, go back to config and set up [secondary], cancel[secondary]

assume the two situations when filling out a multi step form
title: "no saved config" 
message: "you are missing a config for {{list of entities with missing config}} \n You may set default config or go back to config step and assign 
buttons: [use default:primary, go back to config and set up [secondary], cancel[secondary]

for me the main 'crux' is the wordiness of 'go back to config step and set this up' involved in the middle button

Welcome to the site! And yes, words are important.
What I don't understand is the difference between [set it up] and [cancel] options - both will close the modal without initiating any process (i.e, not "use" the incomplete configuration).
Regarding your question about button labels:

The message text shall describe the issue.
It shall also explain the possible options (if they are not clear from the button label)

In your example (I am making up some stuff here, and reduce to two options):

you are missing a config for {{list of entities with missing config}}
You can continue by using default settings, or you can cancel to complete the configuration.

The button labels should then contain unique words from the explanations:

[Use] [Cancel]

or

[Continue] [Cancel]


thanks for your time. in brief "set it up" was short for "go back to step where you set it up at"  The specific wording I used was "go to config step"  I think in trying to obscure my work i may not have wrote the best phrasing of my dialog, I will try to amend when i get time. thanks again

It is never wrong to re-state what the modal is about. To emphasize, if it were a mobile application, a modal with that much content will pretty much cover the entire screen. If information is missing from such a modal, the user may either make a wrong decision or not be able to make a decision at all.
Button labels should denote specific action and not generic. If you are worried about too many words, try using icons or shorten them. For example, 'Go Back To Config Setup' can be '< Config Setup', 'Back to Config' or just 'Config Setup'. If the modal is already on top of the Config Setup page, the Back button will not even be required because the user can Cancel and go back to editing the page again.
